# Select files on grunt

Tags: magento2, grunt

I don't understand how can configure grunt to get the files i want and write where i want.

I'm in Magento 2, and have my own theme, I want Grunt to get the files in:
`app/design/frontend/Name/theme/web/css/source/_theme.less`

and update:

`app/design/frontend/Name/theme/web/css/my.css`

but i don't know how to put it in grunt.

UPDATE

I'm the only one with grunt v0.4.5, who doesn't have the grunt.initConfig in his Gruntfile

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
```

Answer (score 0):

That is better if you take a look here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html#grunt_prereq

For example, we have a custom theme:

[image]

Your Grunt config should be `dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js`

```
Theme: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'Vendor/Theme',
        locale: 'en_US',
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l',
            'css/my' // Your custom less file should be here.
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    }
```

Comment: why i need " 'css/styles-m','css/styles-l', "?

And how i can set the output .css file

Comment: You should read more here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html#grunt_prereq

Comment: yes, but i don't understand, and if i put that files grunt error appear:

Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Name/theme/de_CH/css/styles-m.less'

Comment: without it, grunt create a .css file, but it's empty

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at `dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js`. [Here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js) is the one they have on github.

In that file you can see how Blank and Luma are set up. After that it is a pretty straightforward process to copy them and add your less files there.

Please note that the vendor and theme names are case sensitive.

You will know you got it right if running `grunt exec:yourthemename` doesn't give you any errors.

After having suffered a lot with grunt myself, I would advise regularly cleaning every directory listed on the frontend developer guide in the devdocs after setting up grunt.

Also, after spending a couple of hours trying to get `grunt watch` to work with my theme, I just found that the feature is [simply broken](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1619) (you can skip to the end if too bored to read it all).